# Selenium: how to see full DOM structure?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've seen similar post about this question with the resolution being using the WebDriverWait. But I still kept getting an exception error saying the selector is not present.
Even when I printed `driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;"` at the end of my code the full DOM didn't show up, it looks exactly like the page source, but I need the rest of the HTML's elements

```
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
from ntpath import join
import os
from xml.dom.minidom import Element
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By ## Used for grabbing elements by 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

os.environ['PATH'] += ";C:\seleniumDrivers"
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://jklm.fun/XSNM")

chrome.implicitly_wait(10)
name = chrome.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "nickname")
name.clear()
name.send_keys("Mr.Roboto")

btn = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[2]/button')
btn.click()

join_btn = WebDriverWait(chrome, 1000000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    chrome.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button')))
#join_btn = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button')
#join_btn = chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-text="joinGame"')
join_btn.click()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need the full dom as this seems to be a bit unusual when using selenium?

Comment: There is a button I need to use that doesn't get detected by selenium. I tried different methods of find_element() but none can find it

Comment: I understand, but why would you want to retrieve the full dom is still unclear to me.

Comment: Generally speaking, if selenium cannot find the element it simply does not (yet) exist. There are many possible reasons for that and will have to document the markup and the exact error message to get help with this.

Comment: I guess I don't need the full dom, just the button element but no matter how long I wait Selenium still won't detect it even though I can see it on the inspector tool

Comment: The web page you used in your example does no longer work as expected. After entering the user name it shows: `Sorry, this room doesn't exist anymore. But there are many others!`

Answer (score 1):

Element was in an iframe. I used chrome.switch_to.frame()